# Replacement $\int_{0}^{2\pi }\frac{1}{a+\sin(3t)}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I can not understand why a replacement I tried in resolution with the residual method of the goniometric integrals leads to a wrong result.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\frac{1}{a+\sin(3t)}dt $$

$$a\in \mathbb{R} |a|<1$$

I thought

\begin{align}\sin(3t)&=\frac{e^{3\vartheta i}-e^{-3\vartheta i}}{2i}\\
z&=e^{3\vartheta i}\\
d\vartheta&=\frac{dz}{3iz}\\
\frac{1}{3}\oint_{\gamma }\frac{1}{z^2+2aiz-1}dz&=\frac{2\pi }{3\sqrt{a^{2}-1}}\end{align}

Instead

\begin{align}\sin(3t)&=\frac{e^{3\vartheta i}-e^{-3\vartheta i}}{2i}\\
z&=e^{\vartheta i}\\
d\vartheta&=\frac{dz}{iz}\\
\oint_{\gamma }\frac{2z^{2}}{z^6+2aiz^3-1}dz&=\frac{2\pi }{\sqrt{a^{2}-1}}\end{align}

the second resolution gives the correct result but is much longer. The two integrals should coincide. The results of residues I think are correct I checked them with Mathematica. I fear there is something even trivial wrong in replacement but do not understand what.

Thank everybody.

Comment: i have $$\frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2-1}}}{a}$$

Comment: is $$a$$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: why this adjective "goniometric" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm thinking it's intended to be "angular" or "polar".

Comment: @Joffan, thanks, it looks very likely ; could you confirm Stefano Barone ? It's your question after all...

Answer (score 2):

First of all in both cases the contour on which we have to integrate is same but in first case as t varies from 0 to `2$\pi$` we are integrating around the contour 3 times but in second case only once

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin 3t$ goes three times around the circle in the space of $t\in [0,2\pi]$ but you are only integrating once around in your "first thought" option.